# Zip Mono with 2 other Monos

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I need to get information about a `Book`, `Author` and `Publisher`.

The `Book` contains information about the `Author` and `Publisher`.

I'm getting the `BookInfo` using the following method:

```
bookService.getBook( tenantId, bookId )
           .zipWhen( book -> authorService.getAuthor( tenantId, book.getAuthorId() ) )
           .zipWhen( tuple -> publisherService.getPublisher( tenantId, tupple.getT1().getPublisherId() ) )
           .map( tuple -> new BookInfo( tupple.getT1().getT1(), tupple.getT1().getT2(), tupple.getT2() ) );
```

I'm using `zipWhen` to share the `Book` to the other method calls but as you can see it's a mess since at the end I get a tuple with another tuple inside.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Would even be possible to call the `authorService` and the `publisherService` in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` static operator which may take more than one source publisher (it would be the `Author` and `Publisher`) and combine the results in a `Tuple2` then map the result in-place to a `BookInfo` object.

```
bookService.getBook(tenantId, bookId)
       .flatMap(book -> Mono.zip(authorService.getAuthor(tenantId, book.getAuthorId()), publisherService.getPublisher(tenantId, book.getPublisherId()))
               .map(tuple -> new BookInfo(book, tuple.getT1(), tupple.getT2()))
       );
```

You may optionally make both `authService` and `publisherServie` `subscribeOn` a different scheduler to have results computed in parallel:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mono.zip` inside `flatMap()`

```java
 getBook(tenantId, bookId).flatMap(book ->
                Mono.zip(
                        Mono.just(book),
                        getAuthor(tenantId, book.getAuthorId()),
                        getPublisher(tenantId, book.getPublisherId())
                )
        ).map(tuple -> {
            tuple.getT1(); // book
            tuple.getT2(); // author
            tuple.getT3(); // publisher
            // ... build BookInfo here and return
        })
```

`flatMap()` operator is async by it's nature